# Debugger crashes in Qt Creator when there is an error

Tags: debugging, crash, qt-creator

Since today, Qt Creator's debugger crashes whenever there is an error. Breakpoints no longer work either (the debugger doesn't crash but doesn't break into the code either). Any idea what could be causing this?

This is the error I get in the debugger window:

```
ModLoad: 6dd80000 6de04000   C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7600.16661_none_ebfb56996c72aefc\comctl32.dll
sProcess exited (3221226519)
eProcess crashed
eCDB crashed
dNOTE: ENGINE SPONTANEOUS SHUTDOWN
dState changed BY FORCE from InferiorRunOk(11) to EngineShutdownOk(22).
dState changed from EngineShutdownOk(22) to DebuggerFinished(23).
dQUEUE: FINISH DEBUGGER
dNOTE: FINISH DEBUGGER
dHANDLE RUNCONTROL FINISHED
sDebugger finished.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got it. That's because I was working in release mode, so I guess the debugger was not available. Strange that it lets me start debugging though (the green arrow with the bug on it is not disabled) even though it's going to crash in case of error.